# not declared in scope error in c++ when overloading

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading

I am getting an error when trying to run this code

```
In function 'int main()':
error: 'area' was not declared in this scope
```

I cannot find a clear solution to the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    area(13.3, 67.4);

    return 0;
}

void area(int a, int b){
    cout << "The area is " << a * b << endl;
}

void area(float a, float b){
    cout << "The area is " << a * b << endl;
}

void area(double a, double b){
    cout << "The area is " << a * b << endl;
}
```

Comment: you need to have the function declarations at least before you call it

Comment: @rial Next time please copy the error messages and post them as text instead of a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the functions before you can use them.

Either forward declare them:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// forward declarations
void area(int a, int b);
void area(float a, float b);
void area(double a, double b);

int main() {
    area(13.3, 67.4);
    return 0;
}

void area(int a, int b){
    cout << "The area is " << a * b << endl;
}

void area(float a, float b){
    cout << "The area is " << a * b << endl;
}

void area(double a, double b){
    cout << "The area is " << a * b << endl;
}
```

Otherwise, move the implementations above `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void area(int a, int b){
    cout << "The area is " << a * b << endl;
}

void area(float a, float b){
    cout << "The area is " << a * b << endl;
}

void area(double a, double b){
    cout << "The area is " << a * b << endl;
}

int main() {
    area(13.3, 67.4);
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, since the implementations are exactly the same, just with different data types, consider using a single templated function instead:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void area(T a, T b){
    cout << "The area is " << a * b << endl;
}

int main() {
    area<double>(13.3, 67.4);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put functions prototypes above your main function and you should be fine.